# Bootstrap list-group collapse on click event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, menu, multi-level

I needed a multi-level menu but Bootstrap don't provide anything like this, so I've made a menu/navbar based on list-group, and it works great, I can add multiple levels of submenus but I have on big problem, it won't collapse until I click on the "Pos1" (check bootply link) or other "Pos...".

I need to solution so that when I click in every other part of the website that menu will collapse.

Here is the code and below it you can find link to bootply:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="mainmenu" class="row">
          <div class="list-group panel visible-md visible-lg">
              <a href="#" class="list-group-item"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div class="list-group panel">
            <a href="#menupos1" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#mainmenu">Pos1 <span class="menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
            <div class="collapse pos-absolute" id="menupos1">
              <a href="#submenu1" class="list-group-item sub-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#submenu1">SubPos1 <span class=" menu-ico-collapse"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></span></a>
                  <div class="collapse list-group-submenu" id="submenu1">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">SubSubPos1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">SubSubPos2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">SubSubPos3</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-sub-item" data-parent="#submenu1">SubSubPos4</a>
                  </div>
             <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-item">SubPos2</a>
             <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-item">SubPos3</a>
             <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-item">SubPos4</a>
             <a href="#" class="list-group-item sub-item">SubPos5</a>                                                                    
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/izpRKwzlYb

It would be great if it only work in medium and large resolution because in xsmall and small it should stay still.

Answer (score 1):

Add data-toggle to Pos1,SubPos1 and add data-target="#submenu1" for SubPos1 items,by adding this when you click on menu items or sub menu items the respective menus will be collapsed.i think this may be help full.

check this in:http://www.bootply.com/fY2Vr9qbDo

Comment: I probably didn't explain it good enough. I know how to make it collapse if I click on any other menu position. The problem is that I can't collapse menu if I click on other element of website, for example in normal menu, if you expand something and click on let say scroll-bar or white background then the active menu will close/collapse. I need to have the same effect in desktop version of website.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want the menus without children (submenus) to collapse when clicked?

If that's the case you could simply add data-toggle to `Pos1` children that don't have their own children..

http://www.bootply.com/RNo69avCr1

Comment: I probably didn't explain it right, regular menu works like this, you click on for example Pos1, it expand and when you click on the scrollbar, background, content of the website or any other element menu hide (collapse). My menu don't work like this if i want to hide it (collapse) I have to click on the "Pos1" again. What can I do if i want it to act like normal menu? I hope I explain it ok this time :)